# PyDrive on Google App engine. Can't set the content of a GoogleDrive object from a StringIO object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pydrive

File creation is forbidden in Google App Engine standard applications.

Even **tempfile** is disabled, except for **TemporaryFile** which is aliased to **StringIO**. So I need to set content of drive file with a StringIO object.

The only suitable method I found is **SetContentString()**.

But the method is expecting a utf-8 string and I get a decode exception -

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)**

My code

```
drive = GoogleDrive(get_drive_auth())
drive_file = drive.CreateFile()
drive_file.SetContentString(stringio_object.getvalue())
```

Is there a way I could set the content of a `GoogleDrive` object from `StringIO` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer on GitHub.

It is not documented, but you can set content of GoogleDrive object directly

```
drive = GoogleDrive(get_drive_auth())
drive_file = drive.CreateFile()
drive_file.content = stringio_object
```

Comment: How do you pass a Queue.Queue() 2.7, to this? The idea is to pass a 'data descriptor' that doesnt have the whole data in memory(bytesIO) or on the physical hdd(file).  I'll even take a generator....

Answer (score 2):

PyDrive's [GoogleDriveFile.setContentString](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive/blob/986ad8fb4f68dde6ffaa7c61c951d9573314dea0/pydrive/files.py#L144) method expects to receive a unicode string as an argument, and an optional encoding - the default is UTF-8.

The method encodes the unicode string and uses the encoded string to initialise an `io.BytesIO` instance, like this:

`content = io.BytesIO(input_string.encode('utf-8'))`

You are initialising your `StringIO` instance with a UTF-8 encoded bytestring, and this is causing the error:

```
>>> s = u'ŋđŧ¶eŋŧ¶ß¶ŋŧ¶'.encode('utf-8')                                                                                                              
>>> sio = StringIO(s)                                                                                                                                 
>>> io.BytesIO(sio.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))                                                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To avoid the error, initialise the `StringIO` with a unicode string.

```
>>> s = u'ŋđŧ¶eŋŧ¶ß¶ŋŧ¶'.encode('utf-8')
>>> sio = StringIO(s.decode('utf-8'))
>>> io.BytesIO(sio.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f36c0dc0bf0>
```

Python2's `StringIO.StringIO` accepts either unicode or bytestrings as input, which can cause to confusion in cases like this. `io.StringIO` will only accept unicode as input, so using `io.StringIO` may help to keep the distinction between unicode and bytestrings clearer in your code.